# php mysql pull info from DB and display 1 thing (can't explain in title)

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, that title is horrible but i can't really explain it anywhere but here. i don't know how to word it, or i'd know how to search it.

very basic question though..

### in my database (to make it VERY simplistic):

jim   austin

jane   austin

june  austin

jordan dallas

jenny ft worth

jeremy dallas

kelly austin

kim   dallas

etc.......

### i want a drop down menu that say

Austin

Dallas

Ft Worth

### in php...

Here's the info...

connection  to db is already made way before this. conn.php

table is "leadsn"

the field i need sorted is "moving_to_city"

... the goal, like i said, is to have a drop down with each city that exists.   then the end user can select the city they want (Dallas for example), hit a button, and then it submits the form and searches for "dallas" and outputs

Jeremy (and his info)

Jordan (and his info)

Kim. (and her info)

THAT part, i know how to do quite well... it's just, getting the info into the drop down, without the drop down looking like

Austin

Austin

Austin

Austin

Dallas

Dallas

Dallas  and so on.... that's what i'm having trouble with.

thanks!!!

Comment: Check out SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

NEVERMIND.....   i figured it out...

SELECT * FROM leadsn GROUP BY moving_to_city";

of course i have to sort it by alphabetical, but that's easy...

Answer (score -1):

Have you try with a group by on moving_to_city?

/* Edit */
Example:
`mysql> SELECT * FROM employee_tbl;
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                350 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+`

Now, suppose based on the above table we want to count number of days each employee did work.[...]
`mysql> SELECT name, COUNT(*)
    -> FROM   employee_tbl 
    -> GROUP BY name;
+------+----------+
| name | COUNT(*) |
+------+----------+
| Jack |        2 |
| Jill |        1 |
| John |        1 |
| Ram  |        1 |
| Zara |        2 |
+------+----------+`

source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm